# Is it possible to execute a select query by hand, that will not block other queries?

Tags: mysql

The problem is that if I execute a select that takes minutes, all other queries are blocked in my application while my select is running, what I obviously don't want.

I wanted to see how many rows I have where a column is not NULL, in a myisam table that has 1.5 million rows, 10 GB in size. But the disk is very slow, this is why it takes so long.

```
select count(*) from table where column is not null;
```

Is it possible to run a query like this for minutes, while being able to run other queries?

Even if there is a way to run parallel queries, I suspect the slow disk will still be a problem, causing other queries to become unbearably slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can avoid locking by setting the isolation level to read uncommitted in mysql.

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;

select count(*) 
from table
where column is not null;

SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ ;
```

Comment: good idea but unfortunately this does not help. inserts still pause during this query, so i didnt even check other selects.

Comment: read uncommitted isolation shouldn't lock the table. Insert/update should happen just fine. How did you check if insert is block by this query?

Comment: logged in to the mysql command line, and copy-pasted your read uncommitted command, then the select. then i immediately saw that inserts are not happening. my application shows how much data is pending, waiting to be inserted. it started to grow.